# Why can't I generate a model in new rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-7

I started a new rail project for an api tutorial that I want to take. When I run rails g "model_name"... I'm getting an error. I tried running bundle clean --force and bundle install, but the error persists. I'm using ubuntu 20 and rails 7.0.2. This is on my personal laptop, not my work one and while I haven't started a project on my personal laptop in a while, I haven't seen this error before. Here's the error when running the generate command:

```
rubyplayground@ailouros:~/code/api_build$ rails g model article title content:text slug
```

[WARNING] Could not load command "rails/commands/generate/generate_command". Error: superclass mismatch for class Command.
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:2:in `<class:Thor>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:1:in` '
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:42:in `require_relative' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:1:in` '
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:42:in `require_relative' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/group.rb:1:in` '
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/generators.rb:6:in `<main>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:3:in` '
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in lookup' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in` each'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in `block in lookup' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in` each'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in `lookup' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:73:in` find_by_namespace'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in` '
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>' rails aborted! TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Command /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:2:in` class:Thor'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:1:in `<main>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:42:in `require_relative' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:1:in` '
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:42:in` require_relative'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/group.rb:1:in `<main>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/generators.rb:6:in `<main>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/app_updater.rb:3:in `<main>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake:41:in `block (2 levels) in <main>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake:40:in` block in '
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake:3:in `<main>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in` load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/tasks.rb:18:in` block in '
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/tasks.rb:17:in `each' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/tasks.rb:17:in` '
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `load' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in` load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:506:in `run_tasks_blocks' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in` load_tasks'
/home/rubyplayground/code/api_build/Rakefile:6:in `<main>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in` load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `load' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in` block in perform'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:51:in` invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' bin/rails:4:in` '
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

And here's my gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "2.7.5"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.2", ">= 7.0.2.2"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
# gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem "rack-cors"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end
```

Comment: Give this a shot. run `dpkg -r --force-depends ruby-thor`, then run
`gem install thor`

Comment: Your Gemfile specified ruby:2.7.5, but your stack trace suggests you're using 2.7.0. That might be causing an issue.

Comment: @dbugger That worked! what was the issue with thor?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/thor/issues/721

Comment: Get into the habit of running all commands with either `bundle exec rails` or `bin/rails` instead of `rails`; the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#command-line-basics) uses `bin/rails` for a reason... `bundle exec` adjusts the ruby load path and ensures the right executables for your gems will be in your shell's search path.